# How to share cookies between dryscrape session and request session? Or how to download pdf straight from dryscrape?

Tags: python, session, cookies, web-crawler, dryscrape

Anyone knows how to share cookies between a dryscrape session and a requests session? I am scraping a website that requires authentication and is full of javascript so I need to use dryscrape but wanted to download a PDF directly from a scraped link using requests. However, the requests session also needs to be authenticated and I don't want to authenticate twice. Also, a way to download straight from dryscrape would also help.

Thanks!